# Angular 6 - Prevent Function Change on Click

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a `function` that returns a random number:

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class Component {

    randomPerc(min, max): number {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

}
```

And I'm using this function solely in the HTML Template like this (in many places):

```
<div [style.width.%]='randomPerc(20, 70)'></div>
```

The "issue" is, that the percentage changes as soon as I'm clicking somewhere on the page. But I want to prevent this behavior - **I want the percentage to be static after first time of calling the function**.

I thought of creating a constant global variable, but this won't work as I'm using this function many times. (I want a different random number for every usage)

Comment: Can you post your component code please?

Comment: there is absolutely nothing special about this component except for `
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 - Cache the values in a Map object**

You can call the method with a different key for each element, cache the result in a `Map` object, and reuse it when the method is called again for the same element:

```
<div [style.width.%]="randomPerc('key1', 20, 70)"></div>
<div [style.width.%]="randomPerc('key2', 10, 50)"></div>
<div [style.width.%]="randomPerc('key3', 25, 90)"></div>

<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div [style.width.%]="randomPerc('item' + i, 25, 90)"></div>
</div>
```

```
private widths = new Map<string, number>();

randomPerc(key: string, min: number, max: number): number {
  if (!this.widths.has(key)) {
    this.widths.set(key, Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
  }
  return this.widths.get(key);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muhiia) for a demo.

---

**Method 2 - Use a custom directive**

An alternative is to define a custom directive. In the example below, the minimum and maximum percent widths are defined as two input parameters with default values. Since the style attribute is set on the element only in `ngOnInit`, it is not modified afterwards on change detection.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[randomWidth]"
})

export class RandomWidthDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() minRandom: number = 20;
  @Input() maxRandom: number = 70;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.maxRandom - this.minRandom + 1) + this.minRandom);
    this.el.nativeElement.style.width = `${value}%`;
  }
}
```

The directive is applied to the elements in the template, using the default parameters or overriding them with different values:

```
<div randomWidth></div>
<div randomWidth [minRandom]="10"></div>
<div randomWidth [minRandom]="5" [maxRandom]="95"></div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj81dd) for a demo.

Comment: Great idea, indeed. But I think this method isn't sustainable for me as I'm using the function very often (in loops)

Comment: By "loops", you mean `ngFor`?

Comment: Yes, I mean I could pass different keys via the `index` but I don't like the idea of having an array with 500+ items

Comment: Check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj81dd) for a solution with a directive. I will add it to my answer if it works for you.